# Move files by default (instead of copy) between volumes

Tags: windows, partitioning, file-transfer, logical-drive

The current default for dragging-and-dropping to a volume `F:` different from the Windows volume `C:` is to **copy** the file/folder. `C:` and `F:` are NTFS partitions on the same hard drive.

How can I make the default a simple **move** instead?

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> is a last resort option. Or right clicking.

I'm running Windows Vista.

Comment: So, you have already covered http://www.petri.co.il/advanced_drag_and_drop_vista.htm and are looking (probably) for some kind of a registry hack that would make your default action move instead of copy, even when across volumes.

Comment: @Randolph I will be moving files *a lot* between the two volumes. `F:` is intended as a place to keep my files. I'd rather not have to move my left hand up to the keyboard every time I want to simply move a file. Furthermore, some not-so-tech-oriented people also use the computer, and I'd like to keep it easy for them.

Answer (score 1):

## To change the default drag-and-drop behavior for files to "Always Move":

1. Open the [Registry Editor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027573/windows-10-open-registry-editor).
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and find the `*` folder.
3. Right-click the folder and select "New" > DWORD.
4. Name the DWORD `DefaultDropEffect`.
5. Double-click `DefaultDropEffect` and set the Value to `2`.
6. Still under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, scroll down until you find `AllFilesystemObjects`.
7. Repeat steps 3-5.

## Notes

- Files dragged between different drives or between different network locations will now be moved instead of copied.
- Files dragged from an optical drive are still always copied by default. This can't be changed.

## Source

Good ol' Brink at [TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/38097-change-drag-drop-default-action-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Muntoo - based on your comments it sounds like you are trying to back up, or at least keep copies of files in another location.

I realize this answer might be a bit technical for you, but hopefully it's not too bad.

First, there is a utility included with Windows Vista called [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy). It is command-line, which means it runs from the DOS prompt.

Robocopy allows you to copy files to / from locations with a host of options, not the least of which is a mirroring function. How it works:

Open a Command Prompt by clicking Start and in Run, type "cmd" and press Enter. In the window that appears, you can enter commands like:

```
robocopy c:\data e:\data
```

That command will copy all data from the c:\data director to the e:\data directory. Simple enough, right?

Ideally, you will want to add parameters to the command that perform mirroring, for example, which enables robocopy to mirror the target directory (e:\data) with whatever is in the base. So if you remove folders from the base, it will remove folders from the target etc. each time you run the command.

How to Automate: Create a new myfile.TXT file on your desktop. In the file, enter the following and save:

```
robocopy c:\data e:\data /MIR /Z
```

Obviously change the source and target locations to be whatever you want. Rename the file to "myfile.BAT" instead of "myfile.TXT" (only change the file extension).

Now, you can double-click the file and it will run the command automatically. This command in particular will do exact mirroring based on the parameters, and just might be exactly what you need.

If you want to further automate this, you can make Windows run this BAT file automatically by creating a new Scheduled Task and setting Windows to run the BAT file. [I recommend following the steps here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Schedule-a-task). There should be options to run the task automatically on bootup, shutdown, login / log off, every 4 hours, etc.

**EDIT / UPDATE: Thanks for clarifying in your comment below. I suggest you update your original question with that information. At present, the ONLY way to explicitly move files on a selective basis is as the other commenters have stated and as you already know - using the SHIFT key.**

Comment: Erm, actually, I am just keeping my data on `F:`, Windows on `C:`, and Ubuntu on `U:`. So if I want to move a picture from my Desktop into `F:\Pictures`, I will have to hold down shift and drag and drop. I'd rather the default be *not* having to hold on to shift.

Answer (score 0):

I think this app can help you: [Drag'n'Drop Editor](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.69)

*As you can see, the user interface is very simple. Just click on the action what you want to have by default. This will not affect keyboard modifiers for drag-n-drop, but changes keyboard-free action. You many choose between three availabe default actions:

- Copy file
- Move file
- Create shortcuts

To restore your registry to clean state, use "Uninstall Explorer tweaks" button.*